# VS 2010 and Nunit testing framework setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.5

I am working on an Asp.net mvc3 project (.NET 4). And required to integrate a testing tool. I tried to setup up the Nunit testing framework in my solution but it seems that there is a problem setting it up in  vs2010.

now I want to know if Nunit still works in vs2010 or 
Arent there a clear testing tools for vs2010.?

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

NUnit has a separate test runner program. I believe the workflow with NUnit is that you code the tests in VS, but you have to run them using the separate NUnit test running program. MSTest is the only unit test framework I know of that lets you run tests from directly within VS.

However, there is a VS plugin called [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Installing that gives you an NUnit test runner within VS.

**Update**

Also anyone can correct me if I'm wrong here, but I believe you only get the MSTest runner with versions of VS Professional and up. I don't think VS Express comes with a built-in MsTest runner.

Comment: There's [Visual Nunit](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8164c71-0836-4471-80ce-633383031099/) that'll let you run tests from within visual studio.  There's also [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/), still in beta but pretty cool.

Comment: @R0MANARMY +1, I've never seen this extension before. You might want to post that as an answer, seems like it answers the original question pretty well.

Comment: Per your request: *With [Visual Studio 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/03/13/what-s-new-for-mstest-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-11-beta.aspx), MSTest unit test framework makes a debut in the Express SKUs. It is now available as part of Visual Studio 11 Express for Web and Visual Studio 11 Express for Windows 8*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VS works only with MSTest framework. But you can use some external test-runner:

- [TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/)
- [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/)
- [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Another option - go to NUnit GUI settings and turn on test re-running when test assembly changes. Actually I like big green bar, so I have NUnit GUI opened on separate monitor. When test assembly re-builded, all latest tests executed automatically. If I want to debug some test, I use CodeRush - match better than attaching debugger to NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Visual Nunit](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8164c71-0836-4471-80ce-633383031099/) that'll let you run tests from within visual studio.

There's also [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/), still in beta but pretty cool.  From their website:

> NCrunch is an automated parallel continuous testing tool for Visual Studio .NET. It intelligently takes responsibility for running automated tests so that you don't have to, and it gives you a huge amount of useful information about your tests (such as code coverage and performance metrics) inline in your IDE while you work.

Comment: NCrunch has only 30-day evaluation license. Sadly.